# Prevent manually set cookie from clearing in Chrome Devtools

Tags: cookies, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Version 73.0.3683.75

I noticed recently that whenever I manually set a cookie in Chrome and I either navigate away or refresh the page, then the value I assigned to the cookie is cleared and no longer persists. For some reason, adding a new cookie manually automatically assigns `N/A` to its `Expires / Max Age` property, which didn't happen before. The cookie value would at least persist during the browser session.

I also see on the application panel that the row in which I add a cookie is highlighted red, but I have no indication as what is causing this. Any help is appreciated.

[image: this is what i see when trying to add a cookie on google.com]

Answer (score 0):

Try filling Expires/ Max-Age field. Worked for me.