# Cookies in Asp.Net Identity, WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a project that uses Asp.net Identity (webApi).
In the front end, I used Angularjs and I used sessionStorage to set and get token.

I'm trying to understand, can I use .AspNet.ApplicationCookie to authenticate a user without going back to the server?

Why expire time is showing N/A and what it is mean (See attached image)?
and I want to test.AspNet.ApplicationCookie is expired?

I the following, I'm trying to set expired time and show user alert message when the session is expired:

In ApplicationOAuthProvider:

```
    AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        properties.AllowRefresh = true;
        properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2);
        properties.IsPersistent = true;
```

In Startup.Auth:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = 
         DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active

        });
```

In Angularjs:

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken') == null) {
    alert("Your sesstion is expired !");
}
if (sessionStorage.expired) {
    alert("Your sesstion is expired !");
};
```

None of these conditions is work!

[image: inBrowser]

Comment: Please read [ask] and elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do, and what happens. What do you mean by _"authenticate a user without going back to the server"_? And what does _"None of them is work"_ mean? What do you expect to happen, what actually happens? You do realise the `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie` is HttpOnly, so you can't access it from JavaScript? You do also realise that session storage has nothing to do with cookies?

Comment: Ok, have you see the Attached image? I want to now why Expires column is N/A, and what's mean of N/A? Thank you !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547620/session-cookie-versus-other-kinds-of-cookies, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55246320/prevent-manually-set-cookie-from-clearing-in-chrome-devtools, can you answer the rest of my comment?

Comment: I updated the question. What do you mean by "authenticate a user without going back to the server"? keep user authenticated until he/she sign out or when the session is expired